# SystemParametersInfoForDPI corrupts memory

Tags: windows, delphi, debugging, highdpi

I am trying to use new SystemParametersInfoForDPI function for High DPI application. However, my application crashes (fatal fault) immediately when I return to the caller.

Exception is an access violation when trying execute 00000000.

The parameter that I am trying to obtain is SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SystemParametersInfoForDpi: function(uiAction, uiParam: UINT; pvParam: Pointer; fWinIni, DPI: UINT): BOOL; stdcall;
  Metrics: TNonClientMetrics;
begin
  SystemParametersInfoForDpi := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(user32), 'SystemParametersInfoForDpi');
  Win32Check(Assigned(SystemParametersInfoForDpi));

  FillChar(Metrics, SizeOf(Metrics), 0);
  Metrics.cbSize := SizeOf(Metrics);
  if SystemParametersInfoForDPI(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, Metrics.cbSize, @Metrics, 0, 120) then
    Caption := 'OK'
  else
    Caption := 'FAIL'; 
end; // - crashes here; D2007; Win2016
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Any question like this needs a [mcve] so we can see what you did wrong

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are missing the point. This question is just a note that SystemParametersInfoForDPI performs buffer overflow instead of failing with GetLastError set.

Comment: We only have your word for that. Perhaps there is something wrong with your code. Make it easy for us to verify that by adding that [mcve]. It will make your post much improved.

Comment: Looks like a bug in your code and depending on how you declared the import of `SystemParametersInfoForDPI` as I don't see that in `Windows.pas` - but `TNonClientMetrics` is declared properly there.

Comment: Well, here is your code.

Comment: "You are missing the point. "  Actually, I think you are - you have not actually asked a question, just stated an observation.  SO is a q&a site ...

Comment: @MartynA What are you talking about? Did you see "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" right in the asking question form? I did not ask a question, I shared my expierence.

Comment: "Answer your own question..." sure, but the operative word is **question**, and you haven't asked one, as you yourself state.

Comment: Looks like a bug in your code rather than Windows. You aren't meeting the documented requirements.

Comment: Why are you passing `Metrics.cbSize` as the second argument to `SystemParametersInfoForDpi`?  I think the `uiParam` should be 0 for this query.

Comment: @Adrian Don't think so, docs for SPI say it should be size of struct

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy > If not otherwise indicated, you must specify zero for this parameter. -> SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS -> Set the cbSize member of this structure and the uiParam parameter to sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not sure I am following you. Are you saying function may overflow buffer (e.g. corrupt memory) if you pass insupported cbSize?

Comment: You were told to pass Unicode structures. Do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It does not matter. Happens with UNICODE too. And even if it would work with UNICODE - so what? Function should not touch the buffer behind specified size.

Comment: How about including that sort of detail in the question. Show code that uses Unicode structures.

Comment: Geez, guys. I usually post these things directly to MSDN. But now it says "The feedback system for this content will be changing soon. Old comments will not be carried over.". I decided to publish that info here. Guessing it was a mistake.

Comment: The rules here are a little different. Fit in with the rules and it's all good.

Comment: Your declaration of the function is incorrect, it returns a bool not a boolean.

Comment: It is just a typo.

Comment: @Alex:  Ah, I missed that in the badly formatted version of the page I read, which is the on linked from SystemParametersInfoForDPI.  If you search for it separately, you get a different page where the table alignment isn't totally broken.

Answer (score 2):

Crash part of question - it seems to be a bug in certain Windows builds.

The code in question is not correct.

SystemParametersInfoForDPI work fine only when latest version of structure is used: it should be UNICODE and be defined for latest OS version (e.g. such fields as iPaddedBorderWidth - must be present). In other words, it should have a maximum size among all possible definitions.

This is outlined in documentation, but in a bit weird way:

- Docs for SystemParametersInfoForDpi say: "only Unicode (LOGFONTW) strings are supported in this function"
- Docs for SystemParametersInfo say: "The pvParam parameter must point to a NONCLIENTMETRICS structure that contains the new parameters"

While this does seem like clean up from docs on older Windows versions (2000, etc.) - but it really tells you that you absolutely must use latest versions of structures.

Finally, the bug is that SystemParametersInfoForDpi does not fail with "insufficient buffer" or "invalid parameter" error when it sees unsupported buffer size - as one might expect. Instead it will happily and silently perform buffer overflow. This happens only on some Windows builds.

Thus, if structure is allocated on the stack - buffer overflow will erase return address. And when your code will try to return to caller - it will crash.

Comment: I'm guessing you're assuming the question asks why does that happen?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I am not asking any questions here. I am sharing my knowledge about strange error handling in SystemParametersInfoForDpi function.

Comment: @Alex SO has a Q&A format. You are meant to to ask a question. If you want to share information, get a blog. If you want to post here, phrase it as a question.